# Quantum Espresso installation in Linuxmint 18.3 (Sylvia)

Tags: installation, linux-mint, quantum-computing

I have installed quantum espresso in my computer. It is raising following error on test run with "make all" command. I am not being able to figure out the solution.

IF(use_gpu) ALLOCATE (iexx_istart_d, source=iexx_istart)

Error: Array Specification required in ALLOCATE statement at (1)

I have followed all the steps for the installation. I found this code is written in "https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/kpoints/Modules/mp_exx.f90". I don't what am I supposed to do with that. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIYdC.png)